# regex to get Original Sender from forwarded mail

Tags: regex, email

I need to write a regex that finds the original sender of the email from the forwarded mail content. I need to support various manual forwarding types of the major mail client.

Regex I tried:

```
From\s*:\s*((["|']?)[\w|\s]+\2)?\s*(\<?)[\w]([\w\-\.\+\'\/]*)@([\w\-\.]*)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,22}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2}){0,2})(\>?)
```

Please suggest better regex with all possible combinations. Also in the above is it possible to check only if < symbol(group 3) matches I need to > in the end.

Also possible way to support other than English language

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this ressource](http://emailregex.com/) wich gives you the RFC 5322 Official Standard for email regex. Hope it hepls you.